# SQL Like function for Uppercase letters with or without a dash

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-like

Using SQL I'm trying to verify that a field contains only UPPERCASE characters, numbers and may contain a '-'.
I'm trying to weed out results that have lowercase characters or any symbol other than the '-'.

So far I have

```
WHERE ItemCode LIKE UPPER(ItemCode) Collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS
```

However this allows for all other interesting characters and symbols.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Probably you can use regular expressions in your RDBMS for this kind of filtering, but the syntax is rdbms specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WHERE  ItemCode NOT LIKE '%[^-A-Z0-9]%' Collate Latin1_General_Bin
```

Should do the trick.

The `-A-Z0-9` matches the `-` character or items in the sort order ranges `A-Z`,`0-9`. The `^` negates that expression.

So combining with `NOT LIKE` finds those values where there is not a character that is neither a number, upper case or `-`.